# How do i break out of my while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, break

Doing an assignment, this is my first program so bear with me. I cant get the while loop to end although i have broke it. I need a way to get out of the loop, and what I'm doing isn't working. Any suggestions would be very helpful thank you.

```
def main(): #Calls the main function
    while True:
        try:
            name = input("Please enter the student's name: ") #Asks for students name
            while name == "":
                print("This is invalid, please try again")
                name = input("Please enter the students name: ")


        teacher_name = input("Please enter the teacher's name: ") #Asks for teachers name 
        while teacher_name == "":
            print("This is invalid, please try again")
            teacher_name = input("Please enter the teacher's name: ")


        marker_name = input("Please enter the marker's name: ") #Asks for markers name
        while marker_name == "":
            print("This is invalid, please try again")
            marker_name = input("Please enter the marker's name: ")
            break



    except ValueError:
        print("This is invalid, please try again")
```

Comment: Some more information would be helpful, you have multiple while loops? Which are you looking to break from.

Comment: i am looking to break after asking for markers name. thank you

Comment: So you would like to break out of both while loops? You could use `return`

Comment: yeah, ive tried putting return instead of break but it still doesnt break out of the while loop

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is your indentation. You have told the program to `break` when the `marker_name` is an empty string. I am assuming that you would like the code to finish when all three values are correct, so as such the following code should work for you:

```
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            name = input("Please enter the student's name: ") #Asks for students name
            while name == "":
                print("This is invalid, please try again")
                name = input("Please enter the students name: ")


            teacher_name = input("Please enter the teacher's name: ") #Asks for teachers name 
            while teacher_name == "":
                print("This is invalid, please try again")
                teacher_name = input("Please enter the teacher's name: ")


            marker_name = input("Please enter the marker's name: ") #Asks for markers name
            while marker_name == "":
                print("This is invalid, please try again")
                marker_name = input("Please enter the marker's name: ")
            break

        except ValueError:
            print("This is invalid, please try again")


main()
```

I am a little confused why you have used a try and except? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: No worries, if this fixed your problem please click the tick on my answer.

Comment: i for sure did :)

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you break out of a while loop in python with break as you did already. You should only break if a condition you set is met in the loop. So lets say you wanted to break in a while loop that counts and you want to break if the number reaches 100, however, you already had a condition for your while loop. You would then put this inside your while loop.

```
if x == 100:
    break
```

As you have it now you just break in your while loop after a couple lines of code without a condition. You will only go through the loop once and then break every single time. It defeats the purpose of a while loop.

What exactly are you trying to do in this code? Can you give more detail in your question besides that you would like to break in a while loop? Maybe I can help you more than giving you this generic answer about breaking in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

May I ask why the code block is wrapped in the try-except?

Some suggestions:

- remove the try-except as you shouldn't be raising any errors
- remove the break statement (after marker_name) as the loop should end when the input is valid
- ensure the indentation of all the input while-loop code blocks are identical (your formatting is messed up so I'm not sure if you have nested while loops)

Let me know how this works